# Jasmine spyOn not working properly on AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I'm working on an AngularJS app and I'm facing some problems with Jasmine's SpyOn in a concrete directive.

The directive is quite simple, just call a service's method and when it resolves/rejects the promise acts in consequence, setting some values or another ones.

**The problem**: When I try to mock `SignatureService.getSignatureData` SpyOn does not work as I expect, and acts as if I was invoking jasmine's `callThrough` method over `getSignatureData`.

I've been using spyOn and mocks in other directives and services, and there was no problem with those.

I've been trying to solve this issue the last two days, comparing with other solutions and user's answers, but I can not find a valid solution.

Here's my code:

*AngularJS directive code*:

```
angular
    .module('module_name')
    .directive('signatureDirective', signatureDirective);

angular
    .module('GenomcareApp_signature')
    .controller('signatureDController', signatureDController);

function signatureDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'components/signature/signature.directive.html',
        controller: signatureDController,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindToController: true
    };
}

signatureDController.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    '$rootScope',
    '$location',
    'SignatureService'
];

function signatureDController($scope, $rootScope, $location, SignatureService) {
    var controller = this;

    $scope.$on('pdfFileLoadSuccessfully', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        controller.loadPdfSucceed = true;
    });

    $scope.$on('pdfFileLoadFails', function (data) {
        console.error(data);
        controller.loadPdfError = true;
    });

    function loadDirectiveInitData() {
        var  queryParameters = atob($location.search().data);
        controller.email = queryParameters.split(';')[0];
        controller.phone = queryParameters.split(';')[1];
        controller.docid = queryParameters.split(';')[2];

        SignatureService.getSignatureData(controller.email, controller.phone, controller.docid)
            .then(
                function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    controller.stampTime = data.stamp_time;
                    controller.fileUrl = data.original_file.url;
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    controller.error = true
                })
            .finally(
                function () {
                    controller.endLoad = true;
                })
    }

    loadDirectiveInitData();
}
```

*Jasmine test code*:

```
'use strict';
/* global loadJSONFixtures */


describe('Test :: Signature directive', function () {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('translateNoop'));

    var $q, $compile, $rootScope, controller, $scope, $httpBackend, $location, SignatureService;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_$controller_, _$q_, _$rootScope_, _$location_, _$compile_, _$httpBackend_, _SignatureService_) {
        $q = _$q_;
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $location = _$location_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        SignatureService = _SignatureService_;

        spyOn($location, 'search').and.returnValue({data: 'dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbTsrMzQ2NjY2NjY2NjY7WG9TUFFnSkltTWF2'});
        $httpBackend.whenGET('components/signature/signature.directive.html').respond(200, '');

        controller = _$controller_('signatureDController', {$scope: $scope});
    }));

    describe('Testing directive', function () {
        it('Init data should be set when promise resolves/rejects', function (done) {
            // SpyOn DOES NOT MOCK THE SERVICE METHOD
            spyOn(SignatureService, 'getSignatureData').and.callFake(function () {
                return $q.resolve({...})
            });

            var element = angular.element('<signature-directive></signature-directive>');
            element = $compile(element)($scope);
            $scope.$digest();
            done();

            // ... some expect stuff
        });
    });
});
```

If any one can give me some advice or solution, I would be very thankful.

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE1:** I don't know why, but if I do not declare the `controller` variable in the global `beforeEach`, Jasmine's spyOn mocks the method as I expect.

Now the issue is how to get the controller to test that the controller values are set as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Well... I realized that the problem was that the controller was being created before all, and somehow when the service was mocked the controller ignores it.
This idea came by accident, when I paste the service's `spyOn` in the global `beforeEach`.

So I decide to create a new instance of the controller and the corresponding `spyOn` with the desired result inside the `beforeEach` of each *describe*.

It works. Maybe it's not the best aproach, and I encourage to anyone who have the answer to post it. I'm going to be eternally greatful.

Here's my final test code:

```
describe('Test :: Signature directive', function () {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('translateNoop'));

    var $q, $compile, $rootScope, $scope, $httpBackend, $location, SignatureService, test_fixture;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_$q_, _$rootScope_, _$location_, _$compile_, _$httpBackend_, _SignatureService_) {
        $q = _$q_;
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $location = _$location_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        SignatureService = _SignatureService_;
        // controller = _$controller_;

        spyOn($location, 'search').and.returnValue({data: 'dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbTsrMzQ2NjY2NjY2NjY7WG9TUFFnSkltTWF2'});
        $httpBackend.whenGET('components/signature/signature.directive.html').respond(200, '');
    }));

    describe('Testing directive when service resolve promise', function () {
        var controller;
        beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
            spyOn(SignatureService, 'getSignatureData').and.callFake(function () {
                return $q.resolve({...})
            });

            controller = _$controller_('signatureDController', {$scope: $scope})
        }));

        it('Init data should be set', function () {
            // spyOn($location, 'search').and.callThrough();
            var element = angular.element('<signature-directive></signature-directive>');
            element = $compile(element)($scope);
            $scope.$digest();

            // ... some expect(...).toEqual(...) stuff and more

        });
    });
});
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$q.defer()`, here's an example:

```
it('Init data should be set when promise resolves/rejects', function (done) {
        // SpyOn DOES NOT MOCK THE SERVICE METHOD
        spyOn(SignatureService, 'getSignatureData').and.callFake(function () {
            let deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve({...});
            return deferred.promise;
        });

        var element = angular.element('<signature-directive></signature-directive>');
        element = $compile(element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
        done();

        // ... some expect stuff
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Actually, `$q.resolve({...})` returns a resolved promise too, so... its practically the same.